# não retorna os nomes de clientes do mysql

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, pdo

CLASSE

```
class Cliente
{
    private $db;

    private $id;
    private $nome;
    private $email;


    public function __construct(PDO $db)
    {
        $this->db=$db;
    }

    public function listar()
    {
        $query = "select * from pessoas";

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

OBJETO

```
try
{
 $conexao = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=estudos","root","xxxxxxxxx");

}catch(PDOExeption $e)
{
    die("Não foi possive l estabelecer a conexão com o banco de dados. ERRO=" . $e->getCode());
}

$cliente = new Cliente($conexao);

foreach($cliente->listar() as $i)

{
    $i['nome'] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Coloque essas linhas no inicio do arquivo e veja se aparece o erro. `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Foca no problema!

Comment: o código está incompleto, assim torna-se mais difícil analisar o probelma, coloque as partes importantes, a classe **Cliente**.

Comment: no método **listar** antes do **fetchAll** coloca um **stmt->execute**, e vê o que dá.

Comment: edilson deu propriedade n definida, essa caca ja esta me dando uma dor de cabeça enorme!

Comment: @Golpian olha isto pode ser por várias razões, talvez o próprio objecto PDO $db que estás a usar, experimenta com [este trecho no pastebin](http://pastebin.com/9sV43z1T)

Comment: Posta o conteudo do var_dump($cliente->listar())